# Prove $01^m2^{m+j+2}1^j$ is not a regular language.

Tags: formal-languages, automata, pumping-lemma

I am trying to prove that $01^m2^{m+j+2}1^j$ is not a regular language using the pumping lemma. I am having trouble splitting it into "xyz".

Comment: This seems like a pretty straightforward application of the pumping Lemma.

Comment: @MarkSaving I just don't know what I am supposed to split into x,y and z.

Comment: You don't need to split into $x,y,z,$ you need to prove there is no $x,y,z.$

Comment: @MarkSaving how would I do that?

Comment: @Ferret-2742 See my (edited) answer to your previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4579253). We need to choose a string $w$ (of appropriate length), and for any appropriate split $xyz$ of it, there must be a $k$ such that $xy^kz\notin L$. Here "appropriate" is in terms of the Pumping Lemma definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is similar to the one used in your other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4579253/).

---

To address the confusion, the idea is as follows:
You choose a string $w\in L$. An adversary splits this $w$ as $xyz$ (in whatever way *they* like). For any split that they do, you need to think of a $k$ so that $xy^kz\notin L$.

This is why we consider all possible splits $xyz$ below.

---

Assume $L$ to be regular. Let $n$ be the pumping lemma constant. Consider the string $w = 01^n2^{n+2}$ (here $j=0$). Then, the cases are:

- $y=0$.
- $y=01^m$ for some $m$ where $1\le m\le n-1$.
- $y=1^m$ for some $m$ where $1\le m\le n-1$.

In each case, $xy^0z\notin L$. Note that the last two cases arise only if $n\ge 1$.

This proves $L$ to be non-regular.

Comment: Does this mean that 'km' will be the new  'm' every time you change the 'k'?

Comment: Does the edit answer your question?

Comment: Also, in principle, you can choose a different $k\ge 0$ for each $m$. In this example, however, $k=0$ works for all $m$.

Comment: I think so. Do you have to use every case for y, or can you just use one case?

Comment: @Ferret-2742 Does the latest edit answer this? It is not "cases of $y$"; rather, all splits of $w$ as $xyz$. I mentioned just $y$, since $x$ and $z$ can be uniquely determined from $y$ here.

Comment: @Ferret-2742 Yes, you need to consider all cases. The choices you have are in: choosing $w$, and choosing $k$.